# The Python IDE is saying that my "computer_score + 1" and "user_score + 1" has no effect, any idea why?

Tags: python

Win conditions can't be met because the computer_score and user_score aren't be added to like intended. It also won't register the first few user_plays at random. It's like it decides when to store the value and when not to smh.

```
import random

hand_plays = ['R', 'P', 'S']
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0

while user_score < 3 and computer_score < 3:  # Win condition
    user_play = input('To play against the computer, pick either "R" for Rock, "P" for Paper, or "S" for Scissors: ')
    computer_play = random.choice(hand_plays)

    if computer_play == 'R':  # Computer's rock hand
        if user_play == 'S':
            print('Rock beats Scissors. Computer wins this hand.')
            computer_score + 1
        if user_play == 'P':
            print('Paper beats Rock. User wins this hand.')
            user_score + 1

    if computer_play == 'P':  # Computer's paper hand
        if user_play == 'R':
            print('Paper beats Rock. Computer wins this hand.')
            computer_score + 1
        if user_play == 'S':
            print('Scissors beats Paper. User wins this hand.')
            user_score + 1

    if computer_play == 'S':  # Computer's scissors hand
        if user_play == 'P':
            print('Scissors beats Paper. Computer wins this hand.')
            computer_score + 1
        if user_play == 'R':
            print('Rock beats Scissors. User wins this hand.')
            user_score + 1

if user_score == 3:
    print('User wins.')
else:
    print('Computer wins.')
```

I expect that after either the user or computer reaches a score of 3, the while loop no longer runs and the win statement is printed. Instead, it forever loops stating that the addition statements have no effect.

Comment: Adding one to a variable does not change the variable. This is covered in every python tutorial.

Comment: You need an assignment to store the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand the below code:

```
x = 1
x + 1        # This will calculate 'x + 1' but will not store it anywhere.
print(x)
x = x + 1    # This will calculate 'x + 1' and store it in 'x'.
print(x)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

---

It should be:

```
computer_score = computer_score + 1    # Need to store the calculated value in 'computer_score'.
```

Or:

```
computer_score += 1                    # Need to store the calculated value in 'computer_score'.
```

Instead of:

```
computer_score + 1                     # This just calculates the value, does not store the calculated value anywhere.
```

---

Similarly for:

```
user_score + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change the scoring logic for the computer and player.
Currently, you are only adding 1 to the scores and not properly incrementing.
Revise the logic to reflect below.

`computer_score += 1 or computer_score = computer_score + 1`

Do the same for user scores.